# Auto-populate a list column with a sequential number

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I am experiencing major issues in trying to upload the `package.json` and `sputility.jquery.json` files onto our SharePoint Online 2013 site as advised in the SPSE post:

[''Before beginning the modification, download the SPUtility.js and the JQuery than upload the two file to SharePoint for example on the Shared Documents Library.''](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

Is this not possible when using SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload those files.  Those are package manager files, used in development. What you need is to just use the sputility.min.js or sputility.js files.

Comment: Hi Jesus,Thank you very much for your reply! Have a great day :)