# jQuery - Hide empty field in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, jquery

I have the code that hides empty fields in a list and it works great, the problem is it also hides the edit field and icon which I would like to keep, what would I need to change in the code to stop it from being hidden

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
$.each($('td.ms-stylebody'), function() {
if (!$(this).text().replace(/\xA0/,' ').trim()) {
$(this).closest('tr').hide();
 }
});
 });
</script>
```

EDIT: So I have found a problem, when I group by a column my code does not work, any ideas how to fix both issues?

Here is my password list where I would like to hide fields that do no have a value because the other columns belong to a different content type

I found this article which works when not grouped, I need it to work when grouped

http://www.surfpointtech.com/2014/05/20/cleaner-list-view-boxed-style-using-jquery/

[image]

Comment: why do you need to hide empty fields? In your case the column title doesn't match the column value anymore

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I fix the the two problems?

Comment: for that I need to understand what you are trying to achieve by hiding the empty columns? why not leave them there?

Comment: I have a password list with content types that have different columns associated with each content type, I al using the Allitems view with all the content type columns visible, I am then grouping the view by Content type.

When I enter say a website password the other columns are shown in the group (see image above) I need to hide fields that do not have an values so then the view makes more sense

Comment: have you tried using jslink for that?

Comment: No, can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a jslink file (js) to your listview webpart. Here is an example for a similar problem like yours : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-2625e5e3

It changes how your webpart is rendered and you can change this for every column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this popular jQuery library SPUtility https://sputility.codeplex.com/

with this code example you can hide a specific field

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('% Complete').Hide();
```

This approach gives you a greater degree of control compared to the CSS selectors method which hides all fields of that class

see also: [Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

Comment: Thanks Damien, this is great, in your example you are specifying which field to hide, is it possible to use SPUtility to hide fields that have no value entered.

Comment: hi Matt yes - you put the name of the field  eg Bank Name and it will be hidden.  BTW the other link on SharePoint shows a much more detailed code example which will show or hide a field based on the value of a selected field