# Is there a way to conditionally display fields on a form without using infopath Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, ootb

Looking to see if there is an OOTB method in Sharepoint 2010 to conditionally display fields in a form. I know this can be done using infopath, but is there some alternative that can achieve the same effect? Javascript is a possibility, but I'm looking for something that uses little to no Javascript if possible.

Comment: use Javascript?

Comment: Javascript is a possibility, but I'd ideally be looking for a method that uses little to none if possible.

Comment: You *might* be able to do it with a form customized in SharePoint Designer, using xsl to conditionally display data. But I would go with javascript for sure: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field

Comment: For someone with little to no experience with javascript like myself, would this solution be better than just using infopath if I have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said [ootb](/questions/tagged/ootb), but I have a tool that does this very well.  I have used this tool at two separate jobs (one with Office365 and one with on-premise 2010) with pretty good success.

The tool is called [Infowise Ultimate Forms](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/uf.aspx?src=smm), specifically the Smart List Pro (of which there is a free version).

Here is an example of how the Office 365 version works.

I can edit with more specifics if desired.

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: Thanks Luke, for a non ootb solution, are there any major incentives as to why using Infowise would be better than using Infopath aside from it being free? I'm asking because I do have access to Infopath, but I am trying to find the easiest solution.

Comment: @bberndt Infowise has many no-code features that assist with form creation and other interactions with lists and libraries. Some that my users use quite a bit are customized alerts as well as different one-off actions (workflow-type pieces).