# Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-form

I found another thread here with exactly what I'd like to do: Hide a field based on the value of another field. If WorkspaceSetup= NO, LaptopSetup field is hidden. The other thread is here (I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation points yet)

[Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

I can't seem to get this to work. I'm also a little confused on what the 2nd commenter means as far as the on.change event. This is how I changed the code to reflect my fields:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure below point before using **SPUtility.js**.

It currently will NOT work with:

- External list forms
- Forms that have been customized using Infopath
- Sites with Minimal Download Strategy enabled (feature resides in Manage Site features)

Try below code:

```
<script src="/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> //Edit your correct path
<script src="/Shared%20Documents/sputility.min.js"></script> //Edit your correct path

<script>
// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function () {

    var WorskspaceSetupField = SPUtility.GetSPField('WorkspaceSetup');

    var showOrHideField = function() {
        var workspaceSetupFieldValue = WorskspaceSetupField.GetValue();

        if(workspaceSetupFieldValue  == 'No') {
            SPUtility.HideSPField('LaptopSetup');
        }
        else {
            SPUtility.ShowSPField('LaptopSetup');
        }
    };

    // run at startup (for edit form)
    showOrHideField();

    // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
    $(WorskspaceSetupField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Dikesh. I do have this on an InfoPath for so I guess that explains why it will not work. At least I know that now. I appreciate the info.

Comment: If this is helpful then please mark my answer and upvote as well :)