# List Validation formula help!

Tags: office-365, lookup-column, validation, syntax

I am creating a record center and am having issues trying to have one column (column1) get information from end user and that their answer (choice-dropdown) will determine next set of options that they will see in column 2 (choice-dropdown).

For example:
Column1 - title: "department"
          Choice Column
          Has Options of: IT, Legal, Risk Management, etc.

Column2 - title: "record type"
          Choice Column
          Has Options of: contract, infrastructure, Audio Files, etc.

If user is entering in a file, they are asked questions for the metadata. Ideally, I would want them to select from a choice of departments first, and depending on their selection can break down the record type. Now, please note, the record types will be different options for each department.

I was thinking that if I was somehow able to list validate what their selection is and then feed from possibly a list that has each record types saved.

Any thoughts?  Trying to wrap my head around this for last week!!

Thanks in advance!
-Shasta

Comment: You should start looking into CSR (Client Side Rendering) of the New and Edit forms of the List.

Comment: CSR or SPServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
I am not sure I fully understand the scenario.  It almost sounds like you need to build a content type for each department.  The content type for each could have a unique choice field with appropriate choices.

Option 2:
[$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Option 3:
https://sputility.codeplex.com/

[Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

If this helps, please accept as answer or vote up.

Comment: Thank you! Option 1 seems to be the only thing I can think of for doing.  Could you explain how I would implement this?

Comment: You will create a content type for each department and a corresponding column (maybe a site column) for each content type.  Associate that column to the appropriate content type.  When the user selects that a file is that content type they will be presented to fill out the record type field with the appropriate choices.  You will likely need to name each record type field with an added reference to the department, for example RecordTypeIT.
Resource
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-e1277a2e-a1e8-4473-9126-91a0647766e5