# SPUtility Show Hide Field Based on Value from another field Custom Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, custom-form, sputility

I followed the steps in the link [HERE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field) to Show/Hide a field in a form, based on the value of another field.

What I am having an issue with now is getting this to work on a New List Form, that I created from SharePoint Designer. I have SharePoint foundation 2013, so no access to InfoPath or conditionally hiding a field. The New form needs to be created because of other restraints found within SharePoints default forms.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Jquery** (No need to SPUtility) to a show and hide a field based on your selected value by doing the following :

- Open your customized new form via the browser.
- Edit Page .

[image]

- Add web Part > Add Script Editor .

[image]

Add the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='City']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='City']").val() != "other")
{
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

**Note :** `City` is the choice field and , `OtherCity` the field that you need to show or Hide , so replace this with your fields name

For step by step guide with images [check Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)

Check also alternative method via `SPutility` at [Show / Hide fields based on a drop down field using SPUtility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66388/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-sputility-show-hide-field-based-on-value-from-a).