# List Selection Options Same form - Show TextField

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, splistitem, task-list

I have a simple ticket form, One of the dropdowns in a column include **access**. Below is a sample column, Upon selection of **Access**. I would like a text box to open up in the same form. How Should I approach this ?

```
Request Type
1. Data Issue
2. New Projects
3. Access
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a new single line of text column in list.
2. Add script editor/content editor web part on your list forms.
3. On form load, hide the text field if value of Request type is not set to Access.
4. Register on change event on Request type field.
5. In on change function, check the value of request type. If it is set to access then show text field else hide the text field.

**Reference**:

For more information see answer in below link and use same code replacing City and other city fields by your Request type and name of new single line of text field.

[SPUtility Show Hide Field Based on Value from another field Custom Form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195904/sputility-show-hide-field-based-on-value-from-another-field-custom-form)

Comment: Thanks for the input, this really made sense.. I am currently using a SharePoint 365 where I have an option to only enter a Json query. The SharePoint designer is restricted. What alternatives can I try that you recommend..

Comment: You can use classic experience and the approach mentioned in answer. Or you can use powerapps to customize the forms to meet your requirements.