# Can I have branching logic inside a list (NOT survey) with required responses?

Tags: list

Some of my columns in my custom list have dependent logic.

Example:

Q1: "Does your submission affect customers?"

Q2: "If so, how?"

I would like Q2 to only show up if the user clicks "Yes" for Q1. I've tried setting up advanced column permissions, and when I click "No" for Q1, Q2 gets hidden. However, because Q2 is required, the form refuses to save.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this Out of the Box.  You have to employ javascript to build relationships between questions.  [This is a summary I have used to address the issue.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

However, you can't hide a required field.  You'll need to make the field not required before you can employ the relationship tools.  I believe there is a way to make the field conditionally required form-side, but I leave it to my coding colleagues to assist with that one.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you Kalea. I will look into this. I have no experience with javascript so I will have to do some learning :)

Comment: I wasn't able to add the SPUtility.js to my environment (due to permissions) but I did find some of the other tips helpful and was able to build up the relationships.  Good luck!