# Disable Date field don´t work correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I try to disable only one Date and Time field using jQuery using Script Editor

**Html:**

```
<td class="ms-dtinput">
<label for="Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">Fechados Date</label>
<input type="text" value="31/08/2017" maxlength="45" id="Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeFieldDate" title="Fechados" class="ms-input" autopostback="0">
</td>
```

First I try to disable using id of element as:

```
$("#Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_\\$DateTimeFieldDate").attr("readonly", true);
```

I don´t have any errors on console but field not disabled

[image]

I also try:

```
   <script>

    // Search for the input textbox of DatePicker by its title and get its Item ID 


    var itemID = $(" input[title='Fechados'] ").attr("id");

    // Trim the Item ID and keep the first part which is common for each element of this DatePicker

    var itemCode = itemID.substring(0, itemID.indexOf('$'));

    // Set text input to readOnly  

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='Date']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    // Disable the onclick action on the button

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

    // Disable the 2 time select elements

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateHours']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateMinutes']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    </script>
```

but this line:

```
var itemID = $(" input[title='Fechados'] ").attr("id");
```

Always get

```
undefined
```

How can I achieve correctly it? Regards

Comment: Is hidding whole row an option for you? It may be easier to achieve this than to disable all inputs/icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try your code in document ready or outside?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[title='Fechados']").attr("id");
});
```

Also, depending upon your jQuery version, it could be either .prop or .attr 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170033/make-all-inputs-with-class-readonly

Answer (score 1):

you can use sputility for hide/show any field in OOTB form.

[Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)