# How to Hide SharePoint Library Column (after file upload) Based on Conditions, JS JQuery, Multi-Choice Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-library, sputility

I am trying to use js to hide SharePoint Document Library columns based on conditions. Using SP 2010.

I was able to hide drop-down columns based on an initial dro-down column value thanks to a former post: [Hide/Show field on list form based on value from another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field)

However, I am struggling to hide a choice column based on a previous multi-select choice column.

Condition: If multi-select check box option Functional is checked, show next drop-down choice column titled "Functional". If the check-box Functional is not checked, hide the drop-down choice column "Functional".

The below works successfully for hiding a drop-down based on a former drop-down ( hide unless "Send Email" choice column = Leaders/SME). (Ignore the extra script in the snippet, by error)

[image]  [image]

```
<script src="…/Site%20Assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="…/Site%20Assets/SPUtilityjs.js"></script> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function ()

{ // Get a the choice field

var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Send Email?');

// Hide the target fields in form load

SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value

var ShowHideField = function() {

var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue();

// Hide the 'Functional' field if the selected value is not 'Leaders'

if(selectedFieldValue != 'Leaders/SME') {

SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide(); }

else { SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Show(); } };

// attach the function to choice field

$(choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField); });
```

The below does NOT work to hide a drop-down if a former Multi-select choice column doesn't have "Functional" option checked:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
<script src="…/Site%20Assets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="…/Site%20Assets/SPUtilityjs.js"></script> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function ()

{ // Get a the choice field

var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME');

// Hide the target fields in form load

SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value

var ShowHideField = function() {

var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue();

// Hide the 'Functional' field if the selected value is not 'Functional'

if(selectedFieldValue != 'Functional') {

SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide(); }

else { SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Show(); } };

// attach the function to choice field

$(choiceField.Checkbox).on('change', ShowHideField); });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! By my wonderfully generous colleague.

```
<script src="...(your SP site)/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="...(your SP site)/SPUtilityjs.js"></script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function (){


// Hide all the choice fields



SPUtility.GetSPField('Command').Hide();

SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME').Hide();

SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();



// Get value of send mail option



var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Send Email?');



var ShowHideField = function() {

               var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue();



               // Based on choosen send mail? option hide/show appropriate fields



               switch(selectedFieldValue){



                       case("Command"):

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Command').Show();

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME').Hide();

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

                       break;



                       case("Leaders/SME"):

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME').Show();

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Command').Hide();

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

                       break;



                       case("N/A - Do not send email"):

                               SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME').Hide();

                              SPUtility.GetSPField('Command').Hide();

                              SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

               }



}



// This function hides the Function  field based on the function checkbox value



var toogleFunction = function(){

        var functionalCB = SPUtility.GetSPField('Leaders/SME').GetValue();

        if(functionalCB != ""){

               SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Show();   

               }

        else

        {

               SPUtility.GetSPField('Functional').Hide();

        }             

}      





$(choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField);

$("span[title='Functional']").on('change', toogleFunction);





});



</script>
```